# number of possible permutations of a categorical variable

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, permutation, bioinformatics

I have a dataset with 16 measurements. I have a classfication variable "type" it is either 0 or 1. I want to do a permutation test of my classifier.

I want to create new labels where there is 8 = 1 and 8 = 0

I'm using

```
sample(type, 16, replace = FALSE)
```

It works fine.

But I was thinking that since there is so few mesurments i could run in to a problem that there is more tested combinations than actual combinations. This is a problem since you will get an under/overestimation of your p value e.g. doing a million permutations where only 1000 is possible.

So my question is:

How do I calculate the possible number of permutations of a vector where there is N patients and there has to be P of one and (N-P) of the other.

Secondly just out of curiosity when (what number of possible permutations) would you choose to do a complete test instead of just random sampling.

I know this is most likely simple I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of such [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) is `Choose K from N`

```
C(N,K) = N! / (K!*(N-K)!)
```

For your case `C(16,8)=12870`

---

You can use R command:

```
choose(N, K)
```

For example:

```
choose(16,8)
# [1] 12870
```